# Does Ragnarok start or happen when certain events take place?

Tags: norse, ragnarok, loki

Do the following events occur at same time and will begin Ragnarok? Or does some of these happen during Ragnarok?

1. When Jormungandr circles the entire midgard with it's body length?
2. When Fenrir breaks the magical rope tied around it?
3. When Skoll and Hati devour Sun and Moon, starting Fimble Winter?
4. When Loki breaks the innards in which he is chained with a serpant on top of him?
5. Surtur comes to Asgard from muspelheim to burn it in Ash?
6. When the Niddhogg (Dragon/Serpent) completely chews/gnaws the world tree and makes it collapse?
7. Death of the eagle Vedrfolnir when Yggdrasil falls on it?

Correct me if any of the above events are wrong or if it is in a different timeline with others!

Comment: Ragnarok is a **series of events**, including a great battle, foretold to lead to the death of a number of great figures (including the gods Odin, Thor, Týr, Freyr, Heimdallr, and Loki), natural disasters and the submersion of the world in water. After these events, the world will resurface anew and fertile, the surviving and returning gods will meet and the world will be repopulated by two human survivors.